# eigenvalues of sum of self adjoint operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $0 \leq A,B:H\to H$ compact self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space $H$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1(A)\geq \lambda_2(A)\geq...\geq 0$ and the eigenvalues of $B$ are $\lambda_1(B)\geq \lambda_2(B)\geq...\geq 0$.

I have to prove that

$\forall n,m\geq 1, \lambda_n(A)+\lambda_m(B)\geq \lambda_{n+m-1}(A+B)$.

My attempt to solution is:
\begin{align}
\lambda_{n+m-1}(A+B)&=\max_{\dim L = n+m-1} \min_{x\in L, ||x||=1} \langle (A+B)x,x \rangle\\
&=\max_{\dim L=n+m-1}\min_{x\in L, ||x||=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle +\max_{\dim L=n+m-1}\min_{x\in L, ||x||=1}\langle Bx,x\rangle \\
&= \lambda_{n+m-1}(A)+\lambda_{n+m-1}(B)\\
&\leq  \lambda_{n}(A)+\lambda_m(B)
\end{align}

It seems that it works, but I think I missed something. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't you have $\min$ over all linear subspaces $L$?

Comment: yes, of course, I will edit

Comment: Now, you have $\min$ over vectors $x$. I think you should have $\min_{L}$.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: You have $\lambda_k = \max_L \min_x \cdots$, but I think you should have $\min_L \max_x \cdots$.